# Getting Users in the Sonatype Nexus

Tags: java, groovy, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I am trying to implement additional functionality for **Nexus** that will allow users to create commands and manage their rights, as well as their personal ones.

I implemented this functionality by modifying the **ExtJS UI** and writing **Groovy scripts**. Now I want to implement changes to the **Java code** itself, because it will be easier to manage in terms of infrastructure and it will look more beautiful.

My current problem is that I can't figure out **how to use the security object** (~ [SecuritySystem.java](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/master/components/nexus-security/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/security/SecuritySystem.java)?) to get a list of users from all sources.

---

### I have:

My script uses the [container binding](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/master/components/nexus-core/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/internal/script/ScriptServiceImpl.java#L103) for this *(similar example)*

```
...
def securitySystem = container.lookup(SecuritySystem.class.name)
User user = securitySystem.getSecuritySystem().getUser(userMail)
user.addRole(roleId)
...
```

---

### I want to have:

I need an example or reference to an implementation in the Nexus code that demonstrates the use of such a security object.

---

> I would be grateful for any information.